# Eclipse Tomcat setup

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am trying to setup Tomcat in Eclipse, but when I click on that, it shows an error:

```
May 21, 2017 10:10:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [E:\software\eclipseHelios\lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
May 21, 2017 10:10:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [E:\software\eclipseHelios\lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
May 21, 2017 10:10:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [E:\software\eclipseHelios\lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
May 21, 2017 10:10:22 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [E:\software\eclipseHelios\lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:398)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: do you have `E:\software\eclipseHelios\lib`?

Comment: "click on that"...? What is  " that"?